# CSV Writer omits many items when saving a matrix with many zeros

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am saving a matrix using `python` `csv` writer in the following way:

```
def write_to_disk(csv_path, mtx_norm, cell_ids, gene_symbols):
    print('writing the results to disk')
    with open(csv_path,'w', encoding='utf8') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow(["", cell_ids])
        for idx, row in enumerate(mtx_norm):
            writer.writerow([gene_symbols[idx], row])
```

I have a plenty of zeros in the matrix and what `csv writer` is doing is contracting all of the spaces where there are many similar numbers (zeros in this case) saving in place just `...` character. So, it is saved as a bunch of arrays with various length. Then, I am having trouble opening it up and using. I can open non-contracted `csv` in the following way:

```
data = np.genfromtxt(open(path_to_data, "r"), delimiter=",")
```

But not with these saved by `csv writer` files. Is there a way to avoid this contraction and/or open both types of `csv` files converting them into one format - `numpy 2D array` without these `...` items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work with numpy arrays you should consider to use `numpy.savetxt()` function instead https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html. For example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(0, 10, (10, 10), dtype=int)
a[1:5, 1:8] = 0
np.savetxt('1.txt', a, fmt='%d', delimiter=',')
```

File content:

```
0,8,5,8,0,7,5,8,0,9
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,4
5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,3
9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,5
7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,9
9,9,9,9,2,7,5,0,0,7
4,6,9,0,7,5,2,4,7,5
2,5,1,9,4,9,3,5,3,7
3,3,6,8,5,7,5,8,5,5
9,4,1,2,0,9,2,2,8,2
```

You can load the data with `numpy.loadtxt()` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html:

```
a = np.loadtxt('1.txt', delimiter=',', dtype=int)
```

Then `a` is:

```
array([[0, 8, 5, 8, 0, 7, 5, 8, 0, 9],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4],
       [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 3],
       [9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 5],
       [7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 9],
       [9, 9, 9, 9, 2, 7, 5, 0, 0, 7],
       [4, 6, 9, 0, 7, 5, 2, 4, 7, 5],
       [2, 5, 1, 9, 4, 9, 3, 5, 3, 7],
       [3, 3, 6, 8, 5, 7, 5, 8, 5, 5],
       [9, 4, 1, 2, 0, 9, 2, 2, 8, 2]])
```

Comment: But I can not save in one file this way matrix, row names and column names, but that is what I am looking for.

Comment: Reasoned to store matrix, row names and column names separately. This way this approach works great

Comment: @NikitaVlasenko Row names and column names are not parts of numpy array so yeah - you have to store them separately or need some extra step. For example, you may create pandas dataframe from numpy array and save the dataframe in text file together with all the names. When you load it you can easily get numpy array back. Every action is performed with one or couple lines of code.

Comment: I ended up using hdf5 to store data frames, but will see, maybe storing pandas datafrane is easier, I have not yet tried it